# JWT Token invalid msal

Tags: azure, vue.js, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am currently building a web app using Asp.net core web API as backend and Vue as frontend. THe authentication is realized through msal. I can successfully authenticate within the frontend but when I try to send an HTTP request against the asp.net web api to a protected endpoint, I get a 401 response even tho the JWT is contained in the request header.
As I'm pretty new to the authentication world, I'm hoping for any help here.

appsettings.json in backend

```json
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "<my-tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<my-client-id>",
    "Audience": "api://<app id>"
  }
```

authConfig.ts in frontend

```
import { LogLevel, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '<my-client-id>',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my-tenant-id>'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level: LogLevel, message: string, containsPii: boolean) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      },
      logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose
    }
  }
};

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ['api://<app id>/full']
};

export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
};
```

axios.ts in frontend

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { msalInstance, loginRequest, graphConfig } from './authConfig';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:7158'
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount();
  const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

  if (!activeAccount && accounts.length === 0) {
    return config;
  }

  try {
    const token = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
      ...loginRequest,
      account: activeAccount || accounts[0]
    });
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.idToken}`;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error();
  }

  return config;
});

export { apiClient };
```

The response I get has the following error:
"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience '' is invalid""

The error_description is only present when specifying the audience uri in the appsettings.json in backend. When I do not specify it, only the error but not the error_description is present.

I tried debugging and checked if the jwt was really valid using jwt.io until I came accross that I have to add the audience to the appsettings.json in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://ClientID/test.read
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the access token, the **aud** is `ClientID`:

[image]

Now, I tried to call the **`graphMeEndpoint`** using the above generated access token and got the similar error:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

The error ***"The audience is invalid"*** usually occurs if you are access token audience is not matching the API you are calling.

**In your scenario**, the error occurred as you are generating access token for web API and calling Microsoft Graph API.

To resolve the error, Add **Microsoft Graph API permissions in the Azure AD Application**:

[image]

Generate the access token by passing scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

[image]

When I decoded the access token, the **aud** is `https://graph.microsoft.com`:

[image]

I am able to call the **`graphMeEndpoint`**  successfully:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

**In your case, to resolve the error modify the code like below:**

**`appsettings.json`** file

```json
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "<my-tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<my-client-id>",
    "Audience": "https://graph.microsoft.com"
  }
```

**`authConfig.ts`** file

```js
export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ['user.read']
};

export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
};
```

If you want to call the Microsoft Graph API, then change the `aud` to Graph. If you want to call the Web API, then no need of changing the `aud` to Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I still have some questions. Your "instruction" leads to passing the scope as to the Graphs Api. I don't see, why that is the solution for me as I want to access my personal web api. Nevertheless I've tried implementing your approach and still got the same error unfortunately. I don't know if it helps but in the app registration for my api I've "exposed an Api" with the scope name "full" for testing purposes. In the app registration for my frontend I have assigned permission to the that scope of my web api and also for several Graph scopes (openid, email, ...)

Comment: In your code you are calling Graph Api not your web api and that is resulting the error.

Comment: This is where you are calling graph api `export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
};`

Comment: Alright. Then I am absolutely confused now. I see that there is the graph uri configured but I did not think about it. I don't even want to request against that API, do I? The error occurs when trying to send a PostRequest to my personal web api and even as I configured everything as u suggested, I get the same error including "The audience '<clientId of frontend>' is invalid". Also I did not find a single documentation that helped me yet, how is that even possible(?)

Comment: You are getting the error as the aud is clientid and you are calling graph. Hence modify your code to call your web api and remove the line of code which calls graph

Comment: Yes I got that the aud is the clientId and that this is the problem here, you've explained that very well using the postman example. I thought that the `export const graphConfig = {   graphMeEndpoint: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me' };` is only a configuration and is not really sending a request here. So I would have to completely remove that lines of code and specify the url of my web api ("localhost;8080") instead somewhere?

Comment: As far as I understand I cannot remove the GraphMeEndpoint as that is the endpoint my users get authenticated at, isn't it?

Comment: You can remove the GraphMeEndpoint if you don't want to read signed in user details and just call the web api by modifying the code.